# Automatically "Allow Access" for IMPORTRANGEs in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importrange

I have a set of Google Spreadsheets I want to reproduce (not share) for several users. These users are not going to be able to figure out how to `Allow Access` (for example, some of the IMPORTRANGEs are buried in queries and need to be copy-pasted out manually to trigger the `Allow Access` button).

Is there a script, or some other solution, that will auto-Allow Access in a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

> Is there a script, or some other solution, that will auto-Allow Access in a spreadsheet?

The only solution is that the owner or any editor do the mandatory authorization for each of the external spreadsheets.

## Explanation

[Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start) doesn't include any class or method for Google Sheets built-in functions, so the authorization should be done on the Google Sheets UI by the owner or an editor of the spreadsheet.

The good news is that the access authorization is required only one time by external spreadsheet, so you could add a sheet having something like `=IMPORTRANGE(url,"A1")` for each spreadsheet, authorize the access to each one, and after that delete that sheet.

Note: The user who granted the permission should not be removed from the sharing settings.

## References

- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)