# Vlookup in external spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Is it possible to use `VLOOKUP` with an external spreadsheet?

- `SpreadsheetA` contains a set of a few hundred addresses.
- `SpreadsheetB` is an invoice.
- I want to use `VLOOKUP` in the invoice to return addresses from `SpreadsheetA`.

I tried things like:

```
=VLOOKUP($B$10;"1gmKAibbfQBByX_HNw6pNlQT26cpgeoWhfQcx4UqFk"!ADRESSEN';3;0)
```

but that doesn't work.

Is it possible at all?
If so, can somebody teach me how to do it?

---

Additional information:

The spreadsheet with addresses (A) is a Google Sheet. I want to have all of my addresses in a central place, where I can use them for more than one purpose, e.g. invoices, mailings, etc.

The other spreadsheet (B) is currently a LibreOffice sheet, but I would be prepared to convert it to a Google Sheet if that could solve my problem. Seen the fact that I need individual PDF's of every invoice, Google Sheets isn't my first choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "external spreadsheet"? Is this a [tag:google-spreadsheets] question?

Comment: If we assume this is about Google spreadsheets, the question is valuable. I'll add the `google-spreadsheets` tag.

Comment: ... but, as this question now appears to be about LibreOffice, it is off topic for this site.

Comment: ...but the OP says "but I would be prepared to convert it to a Google Sheet "

Answer (score 0):

As you are OK with using Google Sheets for your invoice use it, then use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=es) to get the external data.

It's worth to say that every first time that [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=es) is used to import data from an specific spreadsheet, it should be as a standalone function in order to be able to see the authorization dialog and to click the related button.

Related question:

[Automatically "Allow Access" for importranges in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98200/automatically-allow-access-for-importranges-in-google-sheets/98202#98202)