# Query + Importrange functions together

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to get range from different sheet IDs. But getting error message.

`=query({IMPORTRANGE($X$5,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$6,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$7,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$8,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$9,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$10,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$11,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$12,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$13,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$14,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$15,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$16,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$17,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$18,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$19,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$20,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$21,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$22,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$23,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$24,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$25,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$26,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$27,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$28,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$29,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$30,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$31,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$32,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$33,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$34,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”);IMPORTRANGE($X$35,”CASES LIST!B9:T58”)},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`

Where X5:X38 refers to sheets ID.

Comment: Instead of `”CASES LIST!B9:T58”` can you try adding single quote like this `”'CASES LIST'!B9:T58”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is using typographical / curly quotes `”` instead of straight quotes `"`. Another possible problem might be have not authorized the access to the source spreadsheets.

To authorize the access to the spreadsheets put each IMPORTRANGE in a single cell. An authorization pop up will be shown, then click the "Allow access" button shown, once the authorization is done, you can remove these formulas.

Tip: On a blank column add the following formula to the top cell

```
=IMPORTRANGE($X7,"CASES LIST!B9:T58")
```

The filldown to get all the required formulas.

Related

- [Automatically "Allow Access" for IMPORTRANGEs in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/98200/88163)